# Task for all objects in model with datetime operations

Tags: python, django

I created this quite important piece of code, but I am not pretty sure is it good enough.

**Goal:**

I have a big task for a database and have decided to use Django-Celery. I want to go through all objects of a particular model and create monthly statistics for each of them based on other foreign objects of it. The task will be run on the 1st day of every month.

The application will be rather dedicated for particular social group. No, I will not have millions of users.

My main worries are:

1. Date and time and time zone calculations.
2. Is it good Idea to do it with Celery? Maybe do it on the statistics view every time somebody wants to see his stats but it may take too many queries?

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import calendar
from datetime import datetime, time

from djcelery import celery
import pytz

from models import MonthlyStatistics, Scope, Entry, Action, Support

@celery.task
def calculate_monthly_statistics():
    """\
    Create Monthly Statistic objects for all Scope models.
    In statistics there are numbers of created Actions, Entries and Supports
    in last month period.
    """
    for scope in Scope.all():

        # Create datetime range for querying
        now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

        last_month = {}
        last_month['year'] = now.year if now.month > 1 else now.year - 1
        last_month['month'] = now.month - 1 if now.month > 1 else 12
        last_month['first_day'] = 1
        last_month['last_day'] = \
            calendar.monthrange(last_month['year'], last_month['month'])[1]

        last_month_range = \
            (datetime.combine(datetime(last_month['year'],
                                       last_month['month'],
                                       last_month['first_day']),
                              time.min).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc),
             datetime.combine(datetime(last_month['year'],
                                       last_month['month'],
                                       last_month['last_day']),
                              time.max).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc))

        # Get Entries for current month
        entries = Entry.filter(created__range=last_month_range, diary__scope=scope)

        # Get Actions for current month
        actions = Action.filter(created__range=last_month_range, scope=scope)

        # Get Supports for current month
        supports = Support.filter(created__range=last_month_range, scope=scope)

        # Create Stats
        monthly_statistics = MonthlyStatistics.create(scope=scope,
                                                      year=now.year,
                                                      month=now.month,
                                                      support_number=len(supports),
                                                      entries=len(entries),
                                                      actions=len(actions))
        monthly_statistics.save()
```